# How do you end while loop

Tags: c++

I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to end my program as soon as the word "NOMORE" is entered.
I have researched similar threads suggesting the use of **"if, break" or "if, go to".**

Although the program will end after entering "NOMORE", I'd like to know if it's possible to end without processing the remaining modules (calcTicket, printInfo).

```
int main ()
{
string licensePlate;
double vehicleSpeed = 0, zoneSpeed = 0, ticketPrice, base = 0, fee = 0;

while (licensePlate !="NOMORE")
{
   getInfo(licensePlate, vehicleSpeed, zoneSpeed);
   if (licensePlate == "NOMORE")
      break;
   calcTicket(vehicleSpeed, zoneSpeed, ticketPrice, base, fee);
   printInfo(licensePlate, vehicleSpeed, zoneSpeed, ticketPrice);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: And currently it doesn't?

Comment: do you want to stop the whole program when its 'nomore'?

Comment: Hello, the program will end, but only after prompting the user with calcTicket and printInfo modules.  I'd like for it to end immediately and only prompt "Press any key to continue . . ."

Comment: what is the need of an if which checks for the 'nomore' when the while loop already prevents from calculating those statements..... the `if (licensePlate == "NOMORE")
break;` will never be executed! if the `licensePlate = "NOMORE"`

Comment: Actually, I have removed the if statement in the code above; however, even if the user enters "NOMORE", the program will end only after prompting the user with calcTicket and printInfo modules.

Comment: try using **continue instead of break**.... i missed to see that you get the info after the while check....... this is a terrible logic! ;)

Comment: using the do while loop would be a better workaround!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume, in asking if it's "possible to end" you refer to terminating the loop, rather than the program.

If you can't change `getInfo()`, I'd structure as a `do-while` rather than a `while`.

```
do
{
     getInfo(licensePlate, vehicleSpeed, zoneSpeed);
     if (licensePlate == "NOMORE") break;
     calcTicket(vehicleSpeed, zoneSpeed, ticketPrice, base, fee);
     printInfo(licensePlate, vehicleSpeed, zoneSpeed, ticketPrice);
} while (true);
```

The premise is that `getInfo()` needs to be called at least once, the subsequent processing is required to NOT occur if `"NOMORE"` is entered, but otherwise the loop continues forever.

If you can change `getInfo()` to return `bool` it is possible to do ...

```
while (getInfo(licensePlate, vehicleSpeed, zoneSpeed))
{
    calcTicket(vehicleSpeed, zoneSpeed, ticketPrice, base, fee);
    printInfo(licensePlate, vehicleSpeed, zoneSpeed, ticketPrice);
}
```

This assumes `getInfo()` returns `false` if it sees `"NOMORE"`, and that it  deals appropriately with `vehicleSpeed` and `zoneSpeed` regardless.   An advantage is that `getInfo()` doesn't actually need to read those values if the end condition is met. Obviously there will be a test inside `getInfo()`, but the caller needn't care about how that is done.

Answer (score 1):

if i understood the question correctly try this:

```
int main ()
{
    string licensePlate;
    double vehicleSpeed = 0, zoneSpeed = 0, ticketPrice, base = 0, fee = 0;

    while (licensePlate !="NOMORE")
    {
        getInfo(licensePlate, vehicleSpeed, zoneSpeed);
        if (licensePlate != "NOMORE")
        {
            calcTicket(vehicleSpeed, zoneSpeed, ticketPrice, base, fee);
            printInfo(licensePlate, vehicleSpeed, zoneSpeed, ticketPrice);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

you will always go to the cal ticket function as there is no condition not to go there in your code. in this code you check for the NOMORE condition if it is there you wont call those functions

Answer (score 0):

If you for some reason cannot use `break`, you can wrap the `calcTicket` and `printInfo` in an `if` statement like `if(licensePlate != "NOMORE")`.

If you are able to use `break`, I would do (to only have one comparison)

```
while (true)
  {
  getInfo(licensePlate, vehicleSpeed, zoneSpeed);
  if (licensePlate == "NOMORE")
    break;
  calcTicket(vehicleSpeed, zoneSpeed, ticketPrice, base, fee);
  printInfo(licensePlate, vehicleSpeed, zoneSpeed, ticketPrice);
}
```

Maybe the problem is with your input and you are not entering your `if` statement at all? Are you entering "NOMORE" in all caps, for example?

Comment: @lallous34 showed exactly what I meant in my first option, faster than me.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to use a flag which is set when the user wants to quit, and use that flag in the loop condition:

```
bool userWantsToQuit = false;
while (!userWantsToQuit)
{
   getInfo(licensePlate, vehicleSpeed, zoneSpeed);
   userWantsToQuit = (licensePlate == "NOMORE");
   if (!userWantsToQuit)
   {
      calcTicket(vehicleSpeed, zoneSpeed, ticketPrice, base, fee);
      printInfo(licensePlate, vehicleSpeed, zoneSpeed, ticketPrice);
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So, why you don't use exceptions?

```
void getInfo(licensePlate, vehicleSpeed, zoneSpeed)
{
    licensePlate = /*get logic*/;

    if (licensePlate == "NOMORE")
        throw std::invalid_argument("NO MORE");
}

/*..define other functions..*/

int main ()
{
    string licensePlate;
    double vehicleSpeed = 0, zoneSpeed = 0, ticketPrice, base = 0, fee = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            getInfo(licensePlate, vehicleSpeed, zoneSpeed);
            calcTicket(vehicleSpeed, zoneSpeed, ticketPrice, base, fee);
            printInfo(licensePlate, vehicleSpeed, zoneSpeed, ticketPrice);
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            /*exit logic*/
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Exceptions aren't really appropriate for this — "NOMORE" is just the end of the input, not an error, and there are simpler (and more-efficient) ways to terminate a loop.

Comment: @Wyzard, I agree  - 'NOMORE' is not error and using exceptions is not the most efficient way to break the loop, but:

1) Code looks more clear
2) We do not repeat useless if...goto  or  if...break.
3) User input operations do not need perfect speed, because they are really slow by definition, so we don't need to worry about little overhead.

Comment: It's not about speed at all. Exceptions are semantically wrong here, because normal user input is not an exceptional situation.